# Implement a C++ which supports 2 level looks with keys of any type

Tags: c++, database, boost, stdmap

I have a requirement to implement a C++ class to support the following

Data:

key - string

subkey - string/double

Value - string/double

key & subkey together identifies the row uniquely.

Eg:

```
[ "key", "subkey", "value" ]

[ "cse", "a", 100 ]

[ "cse", "b", 120 ]

[ "cse", 100, 10 ]
```

Operations:

1) Given a key & return value

2) Given a key return an array of `[ "subkey", "value" ]`

The problem I'm facing is that subkey and value can be both double and string.
One way to solve this is by having a wrapper class which has the ability to store both double and string types.

The first level map will have a string as a the key and the value will be a map.

The second level map will have the key as the new wrapper class and value is also a new wrapper class.

Is this approach right ? or is there any better ways to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

I hacked up a solution using Boost.Variant and C++11 `unordered_map`. The code is a quite nice example for C++11 in action.

You need to pay special attention to the combination of the two hashes
in the specialization of `std::hash<key>::operator()`, it can have a
strong impact on the quality of hashing. For a better implementation
have a look at `boost::hash_combine`, which sadly hasn't been
standardized.

In general what the code does: define a special key type that is
EqualityComparable and Hashable, then use it in a
`std::unordered_map`. You can build all this with just Boost and no
C++11 at all. If you have neither Boost or C++11, you are in a tight
spot. No real testing was done on this.

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>

struct key {
  std::string primary;
  boost::variant<std::string, double> secondary;
  friend bool operator==(const key& x, const key& y)
  { return x.primary == y.primary && x.secondary == y.secondary; }
};

namespace std {
template<>
struct hash<key> {
  std::size_t operator()(const key& k) const
  { 
    std::size_t first = std::hash<std::string>()(k.primary);
    std::size_t second;

    // check for the more likely case first
    if(const std::string* s = boost::get<std::string>(&(k.secondary))) {
      second = std::hash<std::string>()(*s);
    } else {
      const double* d = boost::get<double>(&(k.secondary));
      second = std::hash<double>()(*d);
    }
    return first ^ ( second << 1 ); // not so fancy hash_combine
  }
};

} // std


int main()
{
  typedef std::unordered_map<key, boost::variant<std::string, double>> MyMap;
  MyMap m = {
    {{"foo", "bar"}, "foobar"},
    {{"foo", 23.0}, "foo23"},
    {{"nothing", 23.0}, 23.0}
  };

  std::cout << m[{"foo", "bar"}] << std::endl;
  std::cout << m[{"foo", 23.0}] << std::endl;
  std::cout << m[{"nothing", 23.0}] << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following wastes a little space per key, but has the advantage of being simple:

```
struct Key
{
    Key(string primary, string subkey)
        : primary(primary)
        , is_double(false)
        , string_subkey(subkey)
    {}

    Key(string primary, double subkey)
        : primary(primary)
        , is_double(true)
        , double_subkey(subkey)
    {}

    string primary;
    bool is_double;
    double double_subkey;
    string string_subkey;
}
```

You'll need to implement appropriate comparison operations and/or a hash function.

Comment: Quite a waste of space, but probably will work for most situations. Consider unions or a higher level abstraction.

Comment: @pmr: Yeah I couldn't be bothered looking up the C++11 non-POD union syntax.